# Can't Display SQL Query Result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$query = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM sales WHERE date = CONCAT(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),' ','00:00:00')";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['total'];

echo mysql_error();
?>
```

I have also tried echoing the $row variable without the array and it would display "Array" on the screen. Basically the result of the query should output a number and it's not doing so currently.

Answer (score 3):

Because its the sum of total, its no longer referred to as `$row['total']`.

Try `$row[0]`

:)

Comment: or `SELECT SUM(total) as total_sum ...` and `$row['total_sum']`.

Comment: I have tried that and I have also tried using values 8, 9, 10 since they were the values of the rows that I needed, but they still didn't display anything. Not even a mysql error.

Comment: Try a var_dump($row); to see what you are getting back.

Comment: try echo $query; to see what your query is being built.

Answer (score 1):

first alter your query to this

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM sales WHERE date = CONCAT(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),' ','00:00:00')";
```

use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
```

instead of

```
mysql_fetch_array()
```

Comment: I attempted this with $row and $row['total']. $row displaying nothing and $row['total'] displaying "Array".

Answer (score 1):

First of all the resulting column does to have an explicit name, so you should name it first:

`$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as total FROM sales WHERE ...`

You should use quotes to reference the column:
`$row["total"]`